# How do HTML entities in the alt or title attribute of an image affect tool tips and audio user agents?

Tags: image, title, html-entities, screen-readers, alt

BACKGROUND
I was given text from a copywriter which contained a lot of © . So in Sublime Text Editor, I did a Search and replace with:

```
&copy;
```

A lot of the text was already added to the images in titles and alt attributes. So the text in there was affected as well.

Previously on my own projects I would just strip out all legal items such as registered, trademark, and copyright symbols. Because I figured only the actual text mattered. But this project is for a company that has more compliance regulations, so I am taking into account things such as screen readers. The first thought that comes to my head in a screen reader would be that "copyright" would be spoken? is that correct? does it really even matter in this context?

So should I use the HTML entities?

I have so far in Google found

- [HTML title Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) summarized at w3 schools. but no mention of HTML entities.
- [The global structure of an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html) in the w3c recommendation documents that discusses the title tag. But no mention of HTML entities.
- [Using the HTML title attribute – updated](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/) had good insights on the title attribute, but again, no mention of html entities.

Any experience with this? or other suggestions for things to search? or will I be fine with just plain text

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the screen readers should do an acceptable job with them. You can find an excellent summary of how JAWS handles this at http://accessibleculture.org/research-files/character-references/jaws-all.php. Not all of them are read correctly, but most are. I also tested that page with VoiceOver on OS X Yosemite and it seems to do a good job as well. So, I think you can use character entities as you normally would and expect decent (if not perfect) results with mainstream screen readers.